# How to decorate a form in Lazarus?

Tags: lazarus

In Lazarus, once you undecorate a form, how do you decorate the form again. To Undecorate, all you do is right click on the form's title bar on the top. Then, click on Un/Decorate option. At that point title bar disappears. Now, how do you undo or decorate again? There seems to be no option anywhere in the Lazarus IDE that I can see.

Comment: I've never seen this feature. Are you talking of the same Lazarus that I know? Is this CodeTyphoon? Which operating system? Which Lazarus version?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with this method of "undecorating" a form, the way you can specify whether a form has a title bar is through the form's BorderStyle property.  Select the form in the object inspector and set the form's BorderStyle to bsNone to cause the form to be displayed (when the program is running) with no border or title bar.  Setting it back to bsSizeable will cause the form to have a normal border and title bar.  There are other options you can try that affect whether the form is sizeable and the type of borders it has.

These options may have slightly different meanings on different platforms under different widget sets.